# Cutting the last 3 digits in awk

Tags: bash, awk, substitution

I am trying to make a simple one liner i bash that outputs all programs running and their memory footprint. I have a basic solution witch looks like the following:

```
ps -ely | awk '{ print $8 "\t" $13 }' | sort -h
```

This will print out something like:

```
8348    urxvt
8376    urxvt
19716   X
320820  firefox
```

Now this works, but it would be nicer to have the memory output converted to a more human
readable form, eg '320M firefox' instead of '320820 firefox'. I have tried looking at substr() in awk, but I cannot seem to get the syntax right. Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Comment: there is this http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11580/find-processes-utilizing-high-memory-in-human-readable-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this `awk`,

```
ps -ely | awk '{ if( $8 > 1024 )print int($8/1024) "M\t" $13 ; else print $8 "K\t" $13; }' | sort -h
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I <3 this site :D

Comment: That can be written more awk-ishly as: `...| awk '{print ($8>1024 ? int($8/1024)"M" : $8"K") "\t" $13}' |...`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can do it for you

```
ps -ely | awk '{ print $8/1024/1024 "\t" $13 }'
```

The output would something like :

> 0.082     ps
>   0.089     awk
>   0.053     oracle
>   0.046     mingetty

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/^([0-9]{3})[0-9]*/\1/g'
```

Substitute all numbers by the 3 last.